# Add typescript method's signature

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm using AngularJS v1.2.29 with newest TypeScript. I've had an issue with adding parameter to path without reloading page. I've found solution to this [here](https://www.consolelog.io/angularjs-change-path-without-reloading/), so it about overload method in app.js.

**app.js**

```js
app.run(['$route', '$rootScope', '$location', function ($route, $rootScope, $location) {
    var original = $location.path;
    $location.path = function (path, reload) {
        if (reload === false) {
            var lastRoute = $route.current;
            var un = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
                $route.current = lastRoute;
                un();
            });
        }
        return original.apply($location, [path]);
    };
}])
```

**The problem** is that in the rest of the application I'm using TypeScript, so I'm getting error like "Build: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call". I understand that I should add a signature of this new method as TypeScript doesn't see it. But I don't know what is a correct place to add it.

**Usage in one of my controllers**

```
$location.path("Boo", false);
```

Comment: Could you post the actual code causing?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I've posted code. I didn't thought it's important in this case earlier.